# Mailchimp abandonded cart not working in Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6, mailchimp, abandoned-cart

I have connected the mailchimp account with magneto 2.2 and synced. but abandoned cart emails are not working properly. other automatons are working properly without abandoned cart. please guide.